# function $[0,1]\to [0,1]\setminus M$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $M=\{\frac{1}{n} : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

I am trying to find a simple surjective and injective function $[0,1]\to [0,1]\setminus M$.

let define that $[0,1]\setminus M = Y$.

I can't understand how to handle with questions like this. I understand that the set $Y$ has all the elements as $[0,1]$ without elements like $1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...\frac{1}{n}$ but for example if I want to send $1$,  what the value of function $f(1)$ will be if all other elements are already taken and this function should be injective (because $Y\subseteq [0,1]$).

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x & \nexists k \in \Bbb N: x = \frac 2k \\ \frac 2{2k-1} & \exists k \in \Bbb N: x = \frac 2k \end{cases}$$

[image]

Comment: Can you explain the process of thinking of how did you get to this function?

Comment: @kickstart added picture

Comment: You should have an explicit $f(0)=0$ case.

Comment: @HenningMakholm why?

Comment: Because $\frac{1}{2x}$ is not defined (and $x=\frac2k$ is false) for $x=0$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm good point, modified first case

Comment: Thank you for you answer. how to prove that this function is surjective?

Comment: @kickstart by generating a proof that mimicks the diagram.